# Проблема при передаче сокета в качестве аргумента потоку

Tags: c++, многопоточность, сокет, winsock, winsock2

Когда передаю сокет в качестве аргумента потоку accept выдает ошибку 10061

```
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

std::string ip = "25.82.45.163";

wchar_t* toPCW(const std::string s)
{
    const char* charArray = &s[0];
    wchar_t* wString = new wchar_t[4096];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, charArray, -1, wString, 4096);
    return wString;
}

void th1(int port) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    SOCKADDR_IN sock_addr;
    InetPton(AF_INET, toPCW(ip), &sock_addr.sin_addr.s_addr);
    sock_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    sock_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    connect(s, (SOCKADDR*)&sock_addr, sizeof(sock_addr));
    std::cout << "sent\n";
    std::cout << WSAGetLastError() << '\n';
}

void th2(SOCKET s) {
    listen(s, SOMAXCONN);

    SOCKADDR c;
    int size = sizeof(c);

    SOCKET s1 = accept(s, &c, &size);
    std::cout << "recieved\n";
    std::cout << WSAGetLastError() << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    WSADATA WSAdata;
    WORD DLLVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    if (WSAStartup(DLLVersion, &WSAdata) != 0) {
        std::cout << "EROR WSAStartup\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    SOCKADDR_IN recv_TCP_addr;
    recv_TCP_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    recv_TCP_addr.sin_port = 0;
    recv_TCP_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    int recv_TCP_size = sizeof(recv_TCP_addr);

    SOCKET recv_TCP_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    bind(recv_TCP_socket, (SOCKADDR*)&recv_TCP_addr, recv_TCP_size);

    getsockname(recv_TCP_socket, (SOCKADDR*)&recv_TCP_addr, &recv_TCP_size);
    int recv_port = recv_TCP_addr.sin_port;

    std::thread th21(th2, recv_TCP_socket);
    std::thread th11(th1, recv_port);
    th21.detach();
    th11.detach();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));

    return 0;
}
```

Но, когда передаю потоку лишь порт и уже в потоке создаю сокет и бинжу его все работает

```
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

std::string ip = "25.82.45.163";

wchar_t* toPCW(const std::string s)
{
    const char* charArray = &s[0];
    wchar_t* wString = new wchar_t[4096];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, charArray, -1, wString, 4096);
    return wString;
}

void th1(int port) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    SOCKADDR_IN sock_addr;
    InetPton(AF_INET, toPCW(ip), &sock_addr.sin_addr.s_addr);
    sock_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    sock_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    connect(s, (SOCKADDR*)&sock_addr, sizeof(sock_addr));
    std::cout << "sent\n";
    std::cout << WSAGetLastError() << '\n';
}

void th2(int port) {
    SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    SOCKADDR_IN sock_addr;
    InetPton(AF_INET, toPCW(ip), &sock_addr.sin_addr.s_addr);
    sock_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    sock_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    bind(s, (SOCKADDR*)&sock_addr, sizeof(sock_addr));

    listen(s, SOMAXCONN);

    SOCKADDR c;
    int size = sizeof(c);

    SOCKET s1 = accept(s, &c, &size);
    std::cout << "recieved\n";
    std::cout << WSAGetLastError() << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    WSADATA WSAdata;
    WORD DLLVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    if (WSAStartup(DLLVersion, &WSAdata) != 0) {
        std::cout << "EROR WSAStartup\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    SOCKADDR_IN recv_TCP_addr;
    recv_TCP_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    recv_TCP_addr.sin_port = 0;
    recv_TCP_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    int recv_TCP_size = sizeof(recv_TCP_addr);

    SOCKET recv_TCP_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    bind(recv_TCP_socket, (SOCKADDR*)&recv_TCP_addr, recv_TCP_size);

    getsockname(recv_TCP_socket, (SOCKADDR*)&recv_TCP_addr, &recv_TCP_size);
    int recv_port = recv_TCP_addr.sin_port;

    std::thread th21(th2, recv_port);
    std::thread th11(th1, recv_port);
    th21.detach();
    th11.detach();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));

    return 0;
}
```

В чем здесь кроется проблема и можно ли передавать потоку именно сокет а не порт?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первом случае в функцию передается номер порта сокета, который слушает соединение. В выражении `int recv_port = recv_TCP_addr.sin_port;` в `main` номер сокета имеет сетевой порядок байт, однако внутри функции `th1` порядок байт переворачивается `sock_addr.sin_port = htons(port);` и соединение происходит по другому порту.

Во втором случае происходит та же самая проблема, причем уже дважды, однако в функции `th2` создается третий сокет, который пытается слушать как раз по этому самому перевернутому порту и соединение устанавливается.

Как говорится, минус на минус дает плюс.